# ¿Cómo juntar dia mes y año en una misma columna?

Tags: r, date

Tengo un df con tres columnas, dia, mes y año de tipo dbl. Me piden hacer cálculos con las fechas por lo que me gustaria tener la fecha completa en una misma columna.

He probado:

```
df %>% as.Date(c(dia, mes, año), format = "%d-%m-%a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma más cómoda y segura es usar `ISOdate()` además que la fecha queda finalmente en formato `POSIXt`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(fecha=ISOdate(AÑO, MES, DIA))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# A tibble: 21,610 x 6
     DIA   MES   AÑO PRODUCTO IMPORTE PAGO   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>  
 1     2     1  2020 B           10.1 CONTADO
 2     2     1  2020 C           12.9 CONTADO
 3     2     1  2020 D           10.5 CONTADO
...
```

`> unite(df, FECHA, c(1:3), sep = "-")[,1]`

```
# A tibble: 21,610 x 1
   FECHA   
   <chr>   
 1 2-1-2020
 2 2-1-2020
 3 2-1-2020
```